Plot seasonal mean as a time series for several features
I would like to create a seasonal time series chart that shows a seperate line for every feature in my feature collection. I managed to plot all the NDVI values during my period of interest. So far my figure looks like this:

But instead of the single points that are plotted now for my relevant season I would like to plot the seasonal mean instead. At this point, I got stuck and do not know how/at which point to average the seasonal NDVI values seperately for each feature. Can somebody help?
Here is a link to my code
